# Combining conditions in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I am making a project and it has three types of users. My problem is I want the first 2 category of users to be able to access the information and for the third kind of user i want to display the access denied page. I know I have to combine the conditions and events in Rules under configuration page of Drupal but I am not able to get the result I want.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to deny access is a *content type*, then check this module: http://drupal.org/project/content_access

Basically, it adds custom access rules for every content type in your Drupal installation. You can select the role and the the access type from the `content type` administration page in `admin/structure/type`. Also, it can show different access options depending on the node.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to deny access to individual node this module [node access](http://drupal.org/project/node_access) that "override the permissions for a given content type by setting permissions on an individual node".

Comment: thanks a ton @drupaler1 !!! u made my day :) but yaa for me the module http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess worked as the one mentioned by you is not compatible with D7. anyways thanks a lot man!! :)